# NSMutableArray to NSString and Passing NSString to Another View IOS5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray of names. I want the pass the data (selected name) inside of NSMutableArray as text to another view's label.

FriendsController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayOfNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayOfIDs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    userName=[[NSString alloc] init];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    long long fbid = [[arrayOfIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]longLongValue];
    NSString *user=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/picture",fbid];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:user andDelegate:self];

    userName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    FriendDetail *profileDetailName = [[FriendDetail alloc] initWithNibName: @"FriendDetail" bundle: nil];

    profileDetailName.nameString=userName;

    [profileDetailName release];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result  {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
        transferImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: result];
        FriendDetail *profileDetailPicture = [[FriendDetail alloc] initWithNibName: @"FriendDetail" bundle: nil];

        [profileDetailPicture view];
        profileDetailPicture.profileImage.image= transferImage;

        profileDetailPicture.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:profileDetailPicture animated:YES];

        [profileDetailPicture release];
    }   
}
```

In FriendDetail.h

```
NSString nameString;
IBOutlet UILabel *profileName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *profileName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nameString;
```

In FriendDetail.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    profileName.text=nameString;
}
```

`nameString` in second controller(FriendDetail) returns `nil`. When i set a breakpoint in firstcontroller I see the string inside of `nameString` is correct but after that it returns to `nil` somehow.

-----------------------EDIT----------------------------------------

According to answers I have improved my code little bit
FriendsController.h

```
 FriendDetail *friendController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FriendDetail *friendController;
```

FriendsController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrayOfNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayOfIDs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayOfThumbnails=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    userName=[[NSString alloc] init];

    friendController= [[FriendDetail alloc] initWithNibName: @"FriendDetail" bundle: nil];
}

-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
        transferImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: result];
        friendController.nameString=userName;

        [friendController view];
        friendController.profileImage.image= transferImage;


       friendController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:friendController animated:YES];
    }
   //this is how i take facebook friends list
         if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
             items = [[(NSDictionary *)result objectForKey:@"data"]retain];
             for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *friend = [items objectAtIndex:i];
            long long fbid = [[friend objectForKey:@"id"]longLongValue];
            NSString *name = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"id: %lld - Name: %@", fbid, name);
            [arrayOfNames addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];
            [arrayOfIDs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:fbid]];

        }
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    long long fbid = [[arrayOfIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]longLongValue];
    NSString *user=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/picture",fbid];

    userName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:user andDelegate:self]; 
    [username retain]
}
```

Now when i select row first time it sends name. When i come back to tableview and select another name it shows the old name.

If I delete `[username retain]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`  it still sends `nil` to `nameString`

when I set break point at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` at line `

```
userName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]`
```

I can see `userName = @"Adam Dart"` which is correct

in my second breakpoint at line `friendController.nameString=userName;` I see that `nameString =nil` and `userName = Variable is not CFString`

ARC is set to NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is nil because you did not pass the value in `request:didLoad:` function.

In function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, You create a local instance of another ViewController and set the value of nameString, but you did not present the view and release the ViewController immediately. You actually do nothing in these few lines of code:

```
FriendDetail *profileDetailName = [[FriendDetail alloc] initWithNibName: @"FriendDetail" bundle: nil];
profileDetailName.nameString = userName;
[profileDetailName release];
```

In function `request:didLoad:`, again you create a local instance of another ViewController with image. But this instance is only local to this function, which means no relation to the one created in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

What you need to do is, remember the name of clicked row first in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, here you dont have to create the ViewController instance. When the request finish, set both the image and name to the controller and then present it. But you should avoid user from clicking different rows at the same time, because you don't know when the request finish.

Comment: so in Parent viewcontroller i have declared `@property (strong, nonatomic) FriendDetail *friendController;` in my didload i have allcoted this `friendController= [[FriendDetail alloc] initWithNibName: @"FriendDetail" bundle: nil];` i removed the instance from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and in my `request:didLoad:` i added `[friendController view];
        friendController.profileImage.image= transferImage;
        friendController.nameString=userName;
   friendController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; [self presentModalViewController:friendController animated:YES];`

Comment: I set break point at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` at line `userName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
` user name = @"Adam Dart"`  in my second breakpoint at line`friendController.nameString=userName;`  `nameString =nil` and `userName = Variable is not CFSrtring `

Comment: Still gives me nil value , pictures are ok though. Why it says variable is not CFstring

Comment: Are you using ARC?  If no, when you assign userName in didSelect function, you have to retain it, otherwise userName is still holding nil value

Comment: No ARC option is set to NO in Xcode, I have edited the question. If i put retain only first it sends correct user name, second time when i select a different row it sends old string

Comment: You have to release the old userName first.

Comment: I release in (void)dealloc or in viewdidunload or in didSelectRow none of them seem working, it still passes the data only first time then use old string when i click another row

Answer (score 1):

You have two instances of FriendDetail called profileDetailPicture.  Both of theses profileDetailPicture are not the same.  So in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, the value that you assigned to the nameString will not be visible/available to the  nameString of the profileDetailPicture In the request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad method.

Edit for solution:

1. Create an iVar or property (profileDetailPicture) in the FriendController.
2. Only do one allocation in the request:(...) method.
3. Remove the allocation statement in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Thank you for answer didnt realize that i have changed the code, it seem it works i will analyze it little bit more and put the working in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it has to do with the fact that you assign to `profileDetailName` and then immediately release it?

```
profileDetailName.nameString=userName;
[profileDetailName release];
```

Comment: I guess not, it should have pass the string before release it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate the "first_controller" in your "second_controller"
to pass objects such as your string. and you would call the nameString differently.

example:

**second_controller.h**

```
#import "first_controller.h"
...
@interface second_controller : UIViewController{
   first_controller* firstController;
}
```

**second_controller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstController = [[first_controller alloc] init];
    profileName.text = firstController.nameString;
}
```

Which you'll have to init it correctly, because its two views sharing information.

Comment: nameString is already a member variable of second controller `FriendDetail *profileDetailName = [[FriendDetail alloc] initWithNibName: @"FriendDetail" bundle: nil];
     profileDetailName.nameString=userName;` I am passing the string to the second controller

Comment: you should give us the correct controller.h/.m names which will make things easier to understand.

Comment: I have edited controllers' names. FriendsController is the controller that has table view FriendDetail is the second contoller which should show details of friends when user select a row in FriendsController